# clamav 0.100.1 package not available

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 3.13.0-93-generic x86_64 with antivirus clamav 0.99.4 installed.  Freshclam is asking me to upgrade to 0.100.1 but I can't find the newer package.  Ubuntu Software Center does not have it either.

## freshclam

```
ClamAV update process started at Wed Jul 11 08:26:16 2018
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.99.4 Recommended version: 0.100.1
```

Answer (score 0):

14.04 is a bit old. `clamav` was updated to version 0.100.1 on 18.04 recently. Maybe you should consider moving to 18.04.

Comment: Thank you.  I did upgrade to 18.04.1 yesterday on my laptop but my desktop video card is no longer supported and not even the generic drivers used by GRUB work with a version of Ubuntu greater than 14.04 LTS on my desktop P.C.  I'm stuck with 14.04 LTS on that machine.  The video issue with the newer drivers is that the video goes black and blinks out and back, often so much that it is completely unusable.  I'm running RS880 [Radeon HD 4250] which is no longer supported.   Other than that, the box is still running very well.     (See references in other posts to fglrx)